# Pomodoro timer for LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, software-recommendation, lxde, lxqt

It doesn't have to be a dedicated pomodoro app.
Just a regular timer counting the time down will do.

There are some requirements though - It has to… :

- … integrate with lxde panel.
  Either via being a panel applet or a resizable window present at all screens.
- **Edit:** … count from 25mins down to 0, not the other way round. Thought it was obvious.
- … sound an alarm at the end of a session. Or blink screen. Whatever.
- … easily switch between 25 min and 5 min modes.

Currently, I use `tomate-gtk` with omnipresence achieved with openbox's "Send to desktop" → "All desktops" option.
Unfortunately, you can't resize it and it takes a whole bunch of space on a screen.
Pomodoro timer has to be omnipresent. Period.

Please help folks. Otherwise, I'll consider migration to XFCE even more seriously.

---

**Edit:**
By resizable I mean reaaaaly resizable. So that with omnipresent & always on top options one can make it appear almost like a panel applet.
Seriously, we don't need a fancy dancy app with bells and whistles, animations, 450x600, window, etc. Just a minimalistic panel applet with remaining time and play buttons. That's all.
Minimalism is one of the main reasons why we are on LXDE, after all.

Comment: How about zeegaree?

Comment: Nope: 1. Isn't that much resizable. True, timer is in the title bar and the rest of the window can be moved over the bottom edge of the screen, but still, it is approx 450px wide, so it shadows wide fragment of the Task Bar. 2. Doesn't count down. Shows elapsed time instead.
Code's on Github. Maybe I'll do sth with that. But hey, maybe there's a ready alternative out there.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for exactly the same solution as well:

For now, this what I found for LXDE

- **rsibreak** (will need some confirguration to match the pomodoro timing)
- **goforit** (go UI but timer is only available on the app window)
- **pomello** (kanban integration) Pomello has an option to be omnipresent,
  but I am specifically looking for a gnome-pomodoro equivalent --
  which the abilty to show the time in system tray. The task management
  option also adds to the clutter as well.

I switched to LXDE for over a year now, and still struggling to find this exact solution.

So for now, I'm painfully using pomello as my pomodoro timer.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout breaktimer from snap store. It is an electron app which is very close to gnomo-pomodoro in timer functionality and notifications, but no custom alarm sound or statistics. You can checkout its website for screenshots.

- https://snapcraft.io/breaktimer
- https://breaktimer.app/